# Dataflow job failing with output property missing error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

Dataflow pipeline job failing with message output property missing though passing output parameter as arguments.

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Class interface org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.options.DataflowPipelineOptions missing a property named 'output'.
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptionsFactory.parseObjects(PipelineOptionsFactory.java:1483)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptionsFactory.access$400(PipelineOptionsFactory.java:110)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptionsFactory$Builder.as(PipelineOptionsFactory.java:297)
    at com.example.DataValidationPipeline.getOptions(DataValidationPipeline.java:36)
    at com.example.DataValidationPipeline.main(DataValidationPipeline.java:50)
```

Comment: Is this the same question?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50266890/dataflow-job-failing

Comment: Hi Alex, both are different questions

Comment: Hi, would you mind providing a bit more context. Can you provide the full code and pom.xml files to see which versions of dependencies you are using.

Answer (score 1):

This error message could be clearer. It should read something like: "unknown flag: --output".

I've had a similar error recently when I based my pipeline on the wordcount example but deleted the `WordCountOptions` class. The command line for running wordcount includes `-Dexec.args="--output=something"`. Remove the `--output=something` and it should work for you.

Comment: This worked for me, thank you. But then were does the output go?

Comment: It's hard to say without more information. In general, output in a pipeline is sent to a sink, e.g., written to a file, a database, or a messaging service. https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#pipeline-io-writing-data

Answer (score 0):

What seems to be happening is that the output file may not be set properly. I recommend reviewing [this](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/quickstarts/quickstart-java-maven#run-an-example-pipeline-on-the-cloud-dataflow-service) document where you can see that when you build and run the Dataflow Pipeline you need to set the output argument in the command like this:

```
  mvn compile exec:java \
  -Dexec.mainClass=com.example.WordCount \
  -Dexec.args="--project=<my-cloud-project> \
  --stagingLocation=gs://<my-wordcount-storage-bucket>/staging/ \
  --output=gs://<my-wordcount-storage-bucket>/output \
  --runner=DataflowRunner"
```

This is assuming you are using maven, if you are using eclipse you may review [this](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/quickstarts/quickstart-java-eclipse) document.