# Google Dataflow Runner throws "missing a property named 'output' "

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am getting below error while running beam java sdk model using dataflow runner.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Class interface org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptions missing a property named 'output'.
at org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptionsFactory.parseObjects(PipelineOptionsFactory.java:1488)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptionsFactory.access$400(PipelineOptionsFactory.java:110)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptionsFactory$Builder.as(PipelineOptionsFactory.java:297)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptionsFactory$Builder.create(PipelineOptionsFactory.java:276)
    at com.aail.beam.StarterPipeline.main(StarterPipeline.java:51)
```

I had installed google cloud platform plugin in eclipse and directly created Google Cloud Dataflow Java project in eclipse itself and trying to execute the sample **StarterPipeline** job using dataflow pipeline runner by giving needed arguments as

```
--output=gs://wordcountt-storage-bucket/output/
```

I tried of solving the error by changing the **--output=gs://wordcountt-storage-bucket/output/** argument as **output=gs://wordcountt-storage-bucket/output/** . But it doesn't worked. I tried to run through command line instead of direct run in eclipse as follows

```
mvn compile exec:java \
  -Dexec.mainClass=com.aail.beam.StarterPipeline \
  -Dexec.args="--project=sample-wordcount-beam \
  --stagingLocation=gs://wordcountt-storage-bucket/staging/ \
  --output=gs://wordcountt-storage-bucket/output \
  --runner=DataflowRunner"
```

which in turn throws the same error.

Reference:
[Dataflow job failing with output property missing error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50269633/dataflow-job-failing-with-output-property-missing-error)

I tried following as shown in the reference link but that also doesn't work. So can anyone help me out how to resolve property output missing error.

Comment: Is there some documentation that you were following that seems to be incorrect that should be updated?

Comment: Yeah, this is the link which I am trying to implement practically. https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/quickstarts/quickstart-java-eclipse   At step-10 while I am specifying the arguments i am facing above mentioned error

Comment: Which version of the SDK are you using since the tool says its only compatible with SDKs versioned 2.0.0 to 2.5.0?, If your using a version > 2.5.0, I would suggest that you follow the instructions at https://beam.apache.org/get-started/quickstart-java/

Comment: @LukaszCwik, my sdk version was 2.5.0 only.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your attempting to supply arguments to run the WordCount example but are running the StarterPipeline. The error message is pointing out that the **options** argument can't be specified since the Pipeline doesn't take that argument so try running without it:

```
mvn compile exec:java \
  -Dexec.mainClass=com.aail.beam.StarterPipeline \
  -Dexec.args="--project=sample-wordcount-beam \
  --stagingLocation=gs://wordcountt-storage-bucket/staging/ \
  --runner=DataflowRunner"
```

Please take a look at the [getting started guide](https://beam.apache.org/get-started/quickstart-java/) if you want to run WordCount.

Comment: No Lukasz. I am running correct program only. My word count class name was StarterPipeline only but I had created project-id, bucket names with name wordcount. I had passed correct names only

Answer (score 0):

You might be missing the dependency for the dataflow runner. Check the pom.xml for

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
  <artifactId>beam-runners-google-cloud-dataflow-java</artifactId>
  <version>2.25.0</version>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

See also: https://beam.apache.org/documentation/runners/dataflow/